# I have to run a stored procedure for several dates, but the parameter only takes one date at a time, not a range. Can I loop it, if so, how?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures, declare

I have a set of stored procedures ( in MS SQL ) to run - that needs to get one parameter, a date, but it is only documented to run it in this way:

```
USE SALES
DECLARE @datestamp datestamp = '2022-11-01' 
Exec Tool_UpdateCash @datestamp = @datestamp 
Exec Tool_UpdateNumbers @datestamp = @datestamp
```

So if I need to run it for all of november now, I'd have manually increase the date there after each succesfull running of this..

(The reason for this is that there was a bug in an update on the 1st, I have deployed a fix, but the reading of the sales needs to be corrected/updated)

Is there a more efficient way for me to execute this for a range of dates, can I just set the
**datestamp between @datestamp AND dateadd(day, 14, @datestamp )**

(for running it 14 times?) or like this:

**datestamp in ('2022-11-01','2022-11-02','2022-11-03','2022-11-04','2022-11-05','2022-11-06','2022-11-07','2022-11-08','2022-11-09','2022-11-10','2022-11-11','2022-11-12', '2022-11-13', '2022-11-14')**

Would prefer if the first suggestion works, but the second is also possible, then I could at least just copy & paste it.. Other better suggestions are also welcome, and thanks in advance for any help

I've run it in the documented way and I'm scared to do it any other way as I don't want to cause issues, so I'm trying to confirm other ways to do multiple days without fudging up something

EDIT: pr the feedback and my own tweeks I landed on this solution:

```
USE VARESALG
DECLARE @datestart date = '2022-11-01'
DECLARE @datestop date = dateadd(day, 14, @datestart )

WHILE ( @datestart < @datestop )
BEGIN
Exec Tool_UpdateCash @datestamp = @datestamp 
Exec Tool_UpdateNumbers @datestamp = @datestamp
SET @datestart = DATEADD(day,1,@datestart) 
END
```

This is final query, should be correct now.

Comment: Yes you could use a cursor to loop through a set of dates and call the proc.

Comment: Yes, you can do `datestamp between @datestamo AND dateadd(day, 14, @datestamp )`; why do you feel you couldn't? Though if your column `datestamp` is a date and time value then I would recommend `>=` and `<` logic instead.

Comment: Recommended reading on your User-Defined alias type `datestamp`: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using alias types](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-alias-types)

Comment: In order for the routine to work with date time periods, it needs to be rewritten. Could you show the stored procedures definitions?

Comment: Thank you Larnu, I just wasn't sure. I don't want to rewrite our documented routine with something I just "thought of" without further checking if it would be stupid I guess. 

It's no timestamp used, just date - in the format I posted, yyyy-mm-dd, in the documentation, but when I start typing @ datestamp = , then it comes this infotext that let's me know what is expected, and it says just ' @ datestamp datetime '

Comment: Your while loop needs to compare two different values, not `@datestart` against itself+14days. At present, everytime you increment the `@datestart` value, you're also changing the result of `dateadd(day, 14, @datestart )` so you have and infinite loop.

Comment: Also, never develop and test in a live production environment. If your employer doesn't have a dev or test environment, they need to fix that urgently. If they refuse they deserve everything they get, and you should leave; you can't learn anything constructive there

Comment: @MatBailie yes, there are test environments, but they do not have the amount of data as production has. For this type, every client is small and has weekly backups and it is easily fixed if I mess this up. I have corrected the sql, but seems I forgot to post the update

Answer (score 0):

If you can't rewrite stored procedures to accept dates, you are left to call them in a loop for each date, either using CURSOR or WHILE loop.

```
DECLARE @datestamp date = '2022-11-01' 

WHILE (@datestamp < '2022-11-15') 
BEGIN   
  --PRINT @datestamp
  Exec Tool_UpdateCash @datestamp = @datestamp    
  Exec Tool_UpdateNumbers @datestamp = @datestamp   
  SET @datestamp = dateadd(day, 1, @datestamp) 
END
```

Assuming @datestamp is a DATE/DATETIME type.